# Why is the http.client.IncompleteRead exception raised?

Tags: python-3.x, urllib

I have the following Python 3 code sequence that downloads a zip archive from a webserver and extracts the content, but all wrapped with a timeout.

```py
timeout_period = 60000
extraction_dir = /tmp/archive_contents
response = urllib.request.urlopen("http://webserver.com/archive.zip")
timer = threading.Timer(timeout_period, response.close)

timer.start()

try:
    with zipfile.ZipFile(io.BytesIO(response.read())) as zip_archive:
        zip_archive.extractall(extraction_dir)
except AttributeError:
    # Thrown by the object read() method when the fp is closed by the Timer thread
    pass

timer.cancel()
```

Sometimes, I am presented with an http.client.IncompleteRead exception.

I do not believe the exception is linked to the timeout because it happens before the timeout period runs out and also it's easy to reproduce the timeout period running out and seeing that always is raising an AttributeError exception.

Why is that happening and how can I solve it?

I could just catch it and be done with it, but I want to know why this exception is reaching my code since I do not use http.client module directly. Shouldn't it be handled by urllib, eventually throwing me some other exception unrelated to http.client?